# Create new column with values partially from existing data and rest with a join SQL/BQ

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, conditional-statements, bq

Main Table:

| ID | Table_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | tb_1 |
| 2 | tb_1 |
| 3 | tb_1 |
| 4 | tb_2 |
| 5 | tb_2 |
| 6 | tb_2 |

tb_1 :

| a_ID | tb1_id |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 44 |
| 5 | 55 |
| 6 | 66 |

tb_2 :

| b_ID | tb2_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 22 |
| 3 | 33 |

Output:

| ID | Table_Name | tb1_id | tb2_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tb_1 | 1 | 11 |
| 2 | tb_1 | 2 | 22 |
| 3 | tb_1 | 3 | 33 |
| 4 | tb_2 | 44 | 4 |
| 5 | tb_2 | 55 | 5 |
| 6 | tb_2 | 66 | 6 |

Is it possible to create the output as mentioned above using the three tables ?
For eg : When a new column **tb1_id** is created in the main table , the values are derived from **tb_1 table**, in such a way that , if in the main table there elements under **ID** that are tagged to **tb_1** under table_name column then the values in **tb1_id** will be same as **ID** column , however for the non **tb_1** table, it should be taken from **tb_1** table.

Comment: I think you meant to use tb_2 somewhere in your question but you might have said tab_1 instead?  Also it might help if you labelled "Main Table" in your example just to add clarity.

Comment: I have not mentioned tb_2 in the example, but it is same logic as the data from tb_1 gets picked up. I have labelled the "main table"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select t.id, t.table_name, 
  ifnull(tb1_id, id) as tb1_id,
  ifnull(tb2_id, id) as tb2_id
from main_table t
left join tb_1 on id = a_id 
left join tb_2 on id = b_id
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
insert into output 
    as select 
        maintable.ID,
        maintable.Table_Name 
        maintable.ID as tb1_id,
        tb_1.a_id as tb2_id
    from tb_1 a
    inner join maintable on tb_1.a_id = maintable.ID
 union
    select 
        maintable.ID,
        maintable.Table_Name 
        tb_2.b_id as tb1_id,
        maintable.ID as tb2_id
    from tb_2 b
    inner join maintable on tb_2.b_id = maintable.ID
```

Comment: "from tb_1 a
    inner join maintable on tb_1.tb1_id = maintable.ID" - how can tb_1.tb1_id be joined with maintable id  , tb1_id are 44,55,66 and maintable.ID are 1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: Sorry I think i missed one of your edits to the tables.. I think this is correct now.